# ASP.NET session is canceled before session times out

Tags: asp.net, session

Although the session timeout period is 40 minutes, sometimes (rarely) the session ends before the 40 minutes are up.For example, I browse between pages. Sometimes my session ends before 40 minutes. I couldn't understand why.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="40"></sessionState>
```

And I create the session like this:

```
Session["UsersDetails"] = usersDetails;
```